# How to group MongoDB data by property?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Similar questions have been asked multiple times, but I couldn't find an answer for a problem like mine.

My data looks like this:

```
{ _id: 1, status: 'unpaid', subtotal: 5000, total: 4750, fees: 250 },
{ _id: 2, status: 'received', subtotal: 5000, total: 4750, fees: 250 },
{ _id: 3, status: 'paidout', subtotal: 5000, total: 4750, fees: 250 },
{ _id: <id>, status: 'paidout', subtotal: 5000, total: 4750, fees: 250 },
{ _id: <id>, status: 'unpaid', subtotal: 5000, total: 4750, fees: 250 }
```

What I am looking to achieve is, I want to get a sum of `total` for all records grouped by status and if the status is `paidout` then the sum will be of `subtotal`, and also the latest record with the status `paidout`.

This is my code right now:

```
const totals = await Payment.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        _user: req.user._id,
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$status',
        total: {
            $sum: '$subtotal',
        },
        paidout: {
            $sum: '$total'
        },
        lastPayout: {
            $first: '$total'
        }
    }
}
])
```

This is the returned result:

```
[{ _id: 'paidout', total: 102000, paidout: 97962, lastPayout: 52825 },
{ _id: 'received', total: 60000, paidout: 57630, lastPayout: 57630 }]
```

Not quite the format I was looking for, so any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Do you want latest record where `status: 'paidout'` also group on `status` field and sum either `subtotal` or `total` ? Also what do you mean by `latest record` ? Does `status` field gets updated from time to time ? then how would you say a document is latest ? Is there any timestamp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** Checks a conditions and sum-up on either `subtotal` or `total` field */
    /** Checks a conditions and adds last doc in iteration if `status is not paidout` then `latestDoc will be null` */
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$status",
        totalAmount: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$status", "paidout" ] }, "$subtotal", "$total" ] } },
        latestDoc: { $last: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$status", "paidout" ] }, "$$ROOT", "$$REMOVE" ] } }
      }
    },
    /** stage to remove `latestDoc` field where if it's `null` */
    { $addFields: { latestDoc: { $ifNull: [ "$latestDoc", "$$REMOVE" ] } } }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/up_8yE9oTEZ)

**Note :**

Getting the latest document `latestDoc` is working based on the order documents got inserted. But if your field `status` gets updated for existing documents then if you wanted to get latest document where `status : 'paidout'` maintain a `timestamp` field on which you need to sort prior to `$group` and then push last document to `latestDoc` field.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Also, could you please explain how '$$ROOT' and '$$REMOVE' work here?

Comment: @sadmansh : those are system variables check this : (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/index.html)